# Simulating the discontinued Lawry's Roasted Garlic Salt?

Tags: spices, garlic, restaurant-mimicry

Lawry's Roasted Garlic Salt was simply the best spice I've ever had. And  had I known it was discontinued I would've bought a few cases.

If you're familiar with it can you recommend something similar.

Comment: I think Mrs dash garlic and herb is pretty similar

Comment: The ingredient list from the back of the bottle, in order: Salt, sugar, modified corn starch, roasted garlic, spices (including oregano and basil), natural flavor, extractives of carrots.

Comment: This was flagged for closure because this site doesn't do recipe requests. However, since [you're trying to mimic an existing recipe](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1551/17272), it might be acceptable. Have you tried duplicating it yourself? What were the particular flavor components of it that you find lacking in other spice blends?

Comment: Ok, well I don't want the question closed I've remove the request to create an equivalent instead of just finding one.

(If someone offered a recipe without hinting at asking one would it also be flagged for closure?)

Comment: Asking for a substitute for a discontinued product is certainly fine, the close voters were probably trying to follow the law, not the spirit.

Comment: And that means the law is not effective because all it does is leave a sour taste.

Comment: @Cindy if you post the nutritional values as well, I might be able to come up with a simulation...

Comment: Restaurant mimicry has been considered on topic since the early days of this site, as you have a specific goal that other people would be familiar with, and this would be similar  (Although it might get iffy if you asked some hole in the wall restaurant unless you also tell what you’ve tried and how it differed from the restaurant)

Comment: @Fabby If you do an image search for Lawry's Roasted Garlic Salt you should find an image of the back of the bottle. You should see the info there.

Answer (score 5):

We know that:

- [1.1g contains 13% of the daily value of sodium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITKFK.jpg) which according to the [FDA is < 2400mg/day](https://www.fda.gov/Food/ResourcesForYou/Consumers/ucm315393.htm) so 320 mg checks out correctly.
- The total weight of the entire container is [201 g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6dK3.jpg) and the amount of servings is 183, so that checks out as well. (183 * 1.1)
- The ingredients are in order of weight:

  - salt
  - sugar
  - modified corn starch
  - roasted garlic
  - spices (including oregano and basil)
  - natural flavor
  - extractives  [[sic]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic) of carrots

  and that means the content of salt is highest, then sugar, then starch, ... until the carrot extract.
- Salt is [NaCl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride) and [1 teaspoon weighs 10.7g](https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/volume-to-weight) so 1/4 teaspoon weighs 2.7g, not the 1.1g that the container displays, so the other ingredients must be lighter to come to a weight of 1.1g for the overall mixture
- [1 teaspoon of sugar weighs 3.95g](https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/volume-to-weight)
- [1 teaspoon of corn starch weighs 2.77g](https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/volume-to-weight)
- [1ml of garlic flakes weighs 0.35g](http://www.fao.org/docrep/017/ap815e/ap815e.pdf), so [1 teaspoon weighs 0.07g](https://www.metric-conversions.org/volume/milliliters-to-us-teaspoons.htm)
- [1ml of BBQ spices weighs 0.48g](http://www.fao.org/docrep/017/ap815e/ap815e.pdf), so [1 teaspoon weighs 0.1g](https://www.metric-conversions.org/volume/milliliters-to-us-teaspoons.htm)

"Natural flavor" and "carrot extract"  are really hard to find and are the ingredients with the least amount of weight in this recipe so I'll leave them out of this for the moment.

If we would mix 5 teaspoons of the above ingredients we'd come to a total of 0.8795g, which is too low so let's increase the cheapest and heaviest ingredient:

- **1.4 teaspoons of salt + 1 teaspoon sugar + 1 teaspoon of corn starch + 1 teaspoon of garlic +1 of spices is 1.09 g**

That leaves you to play with 0.01g of natural flavor and carrot extract to get it just right, but the above should be 99% correct.

Comment: Great answer! I would be very interested to know the results from anyone who tries this.

Comment: @Cindy I don't know what the original tastes like as I've never used it, so I just took a best shot at recreating a recipe from best estimates but if you know what it tastes like, it'l take just 5 teaspoons of ingredients you already have in the house to test it out...

Comment: Sorry, I've never used it. I'm hoping that someone who is familiar with it will try your recipe and let us know.

Comment: Looking at those ingredients I'm going to go out on a limb and say it tastes mostly like salt.

Comment: And I cook without salt and with a ton of herbs...   **0:-)** @Sobachatina

Comment: I would like to try it since I posted the question!  But are there different flavors of garlic flakes? ... roasted?... where does one procure.

Comment: Where I live, garlic flakes are sometimes called "powdered garlic" and it's available in the herbs section of any supermarket. @RandyZeitman

Comment: Will it taste like Lawry's or just garlic?

Comment: I've never tasted Lawry's, I just went by ingredients and what it looks like and cost and then reverse-engineered...  @RandyZeitman

Answer (score 4):

I am also looking to replace the Roasted Garlic salt from Lawry's. The flavor was perfect and just a little dash or two enhanced the flavor of so many things.

As an experiment, I tried blending one part 'Lawry's Seasoned Salt' to one part 'McCormicks Roasted Garlic' (something I bought looking for an alternative) in a small shaker.  I compared the two (yes, I have about 1/2 inch left in my last bottle of 'Lawry's Roasted Garlic Salt'!) and it isn’t too bad. I put a little bit on boiled potatoes and it is by far the closest thing I have found to date.

I will be experimenting further in the future hoping to make it a closer match.

Comment: Thank you Tommy. I'll give that a go!  I have 4" left in my shaker and you're welcome to one of them for your help!  (Yes, I'd really send it.)   Is the MCCORMICK the ROASTED GARLIC POWDER?  

But I also see this ... "McCormick Grill Mates Roasted Garlic & Herb" to try in combo.

And I can tell you the McCormick Black Garlic Powder Seasoning is already $9 ... up from $6 ... up from $3. I bought ten at $6. I go through a bottle every two weeks ... I'd like to buy a case but have not yet been able to.